# Trying to Understand why Lazy Async Properties are "Bad" and how to maintain Parent > Child relationship in classes

Tags: c#, oop, asynchronous, async-await

I've read a couple posts on why lazy loaded async properties are pointless and that a method should be used instead.

In my example code below... when not async... when I assign the list of parent objects to a datagridview control, the control knows to cascade down into the child objects.  My inclination would be to make the child list getter asynchronous to maintain this relationship; however, posts I'm reading say that this should turn into an asynchronous method instead of being in a "getter".

If I turn the child list into a method then, the datagrid no longer knows the relationship exists and to cascade down to the child list.

I would like to either...

1. Change the retrieval of child objects to a method but **still maintain the relationship**
2. Implement a lazy child list property (apparently "bad"?)

Thanks in advance for any support you can provide helping me to understand this.

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid parentsGrid = new DataGrid(); // << i am using a 3rd party grid control here that knows to cascade down into child objects
        parentsGrid.DataSource = await Parents.FindAllAsync();  // << because of the List<Children> property, grid understands how to cascade through the relationships
    }
}

public class Parents
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    private List<Children> childrenList;
    public List<Children> ChildrenList //how do i do a lazy instantation here and/or why is it "bad"
    {
        get
        {
            if (childrenList == null) { childrenList = Children.FindByParentIDAsync(ID).Result; } // << i know not async, question is how to make
            return childrenList;
        }
        set { childrenList = value; }
    }

    public static async Task<List<Parents>> FindAllAsync()
    {
        List<Parents> pl = new List<Parents>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Parents", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    await sqlCommand.Connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await sqlDataReader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            pl.Add(readData(sqlDataReader));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        return pl;
    }

    private static Parents readData(SqlDataReader sqlr)
    {
        //eto mappings happen here, no need to show code...
        return new Parents();
    }
}

public class Children
{ 
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public async static Task<List<Children>> FindByParentIDAsync(Guid ParentID)
    {
        List<Children> pl = new List<Children>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT FROM Children WHERE ParentID = @ParentID", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ParentID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ParentID;

                    await sqlCommand.Connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await sqlDataReader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            pl.Add(readData(sqlDataReader));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        return pl;
    }

    private static Children readData(SqlDataReader sqlr)
    {
        //eto mappings happen here, no need to show code...
        return new Children();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please never write `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`. It's a terrible anti-pattern.

Comment: I usually throw a more meaningful written out exception, this is just some trimmed down code for an example.  I get your point...

Comment: `async` isn't a valid modifier on a property, so you can't really have an `async property`. As for why it is "bad" to lazy load a collection property, well it'd be hard to say... it probably depends on the case? In this case it seems like lazy loading the `ChildrenList` is an `N+1` problem. You load the `Parent`s, then for each `Parent` you load the children. That's (potentially) a lot of calls to the database when you could just eager load `ChildrenList` with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Turn `ChildrenList` into a method `Task<List<Children>> GetChildren()`, do you null check in there/initialization/caching and be done with it.

Comment: @Joshua - The above is psuedocode but in my real world scenario it's more like a uber/lyft type scenario.  One driver can have a very many trips.  In my non-async data layer code I've been using for years, I like to keep the c# classes exactly mimicking the table structures and because of the loading time implemented the "lazy" loading pattern.

Comment: @Johan, thanks for the suggestion... I think maybe I didn't make it clear enough in my question.  If I make the property into a method, how does the grid still know the relationship exists?  I'm not using EF or a context file.

Comment: Another option is to keep your prop `ChildrenList` but change it to return `Task<List<Children>>` instead of `List<Children>`?

Comment: @Johan, I can keep looking into that.  I read that they actively chose not to allow async properties in c#.  Just trying to find the way to keep the relationship but still get the async function.  Thanks.

Comment: Returning a Task from a prop isn't an async property.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm just confused in general then.  I could pass the task<list<children>> through the getter from an async method but, I can't see how to also get the async functionality when doing that (because you can't set the "getter" async and await the method)  I will fiddle around with that unless you have a sample?  Thanks.

Comment: @beeker - I always try to write code so that I don't need to put in `try`/`catch` blocks at all. If I ever do, I'm only handling specific exceptions that I can meaningfully handle.

Comment: @beeker "how does the grid still know the relationship exists?" IMHO keep the list property, but leave the value null. Write the async load method, call it, then tell your grid to refresh.